# How to get landscape float with correct numbering?

Tags: floats, landscape, afterpage

I am setting a figure in landscape and then two other figures in normal mode. However, the landscape figure goes between the normal figures and the numbering gets messed up, including in the table of contents. How do I avoid the numbers being in the wrong order?

Unfortunately, I was not able to create a minimal example where this happens. Here is the structure of what I am using:

```
\clearpage
\begin{landscape}
  % figure 2
\end{landscape}
% figure 1
% figure 3
```

I'll tried with and without `\clearpage` before and after the landscape environment.

**Edit:**

Due to the comment by David, I saw that it is actually the following that causes the problem:

```
\afterpage{
  \clearpage
  \begin{landscape}
    % figure 2
  \end{landscape}
}
% figure 1
% figure 3
```

**Edit 2:**

Finally, a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\blindtext[4]
\afterpage{
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
... figure contents ...
\caption{Figure 1}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
}
\begin{figure}
... figure contents ...
\caption{Figure 2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
... figure contents ...
\caption{Figure 3}
\end{figure}
\blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

Note: Removing the [H] option of the third figure produces a whole page for just one small figure which isn't desired.

**Edit 3:**

Removing the [H] option does not change the order of figures either.

**Edit 4:**

For reference, here is what seems to be the result I was looking for: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472608/36836

Comment: the `\clearpage` won't do anything as `landscape` does `\clearpage` itself but no floats should go out of sequence. Please show an example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I totally agree with you that an example would be great. In particular if it is as you say and `landscape` should not make floats go out of sequence which might indicate that I have messed up my document in some other way. I cannot post my whole document here. But if I have managed to reproduce it in another example, I'll post it here...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay great. Due to your hints, I think I found the culprit now. There is actually an `\afterpage{...}` surrounding the `landscape` environment (including the `\clearpage`!) - I guess to not cut off a page suddenly. Moving the `\clearpage` in front of the `\afterpage` command does the trick. Is this the way to go?

Comment: well since the whole purpose of `\afterpage` is to move things out of sequence than yes it will move things out of sequence. Almost certainly not using `\afterpage` is the way to go but hard to say in general.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My purpose of using `\afterpage` was to get the text before and after a landscape page to "float" nicely so to not get any larger vertical space. Do you know of a better alternative to this?

Comment: but if you put `\clearpage` before that you force a page break anyway, and do note the afterpage documentation for the general robustness of that package.,,,

Comment: in particular you haven't shown why figure 1 wasn't output at the same page break as the \afterpage

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Unfortunately, I don't know what "robustness" means here. You were right that introducing `\clearpage` before `\afterpage` doesn't make sense. So I removed it again. Figure 1 is output as the last figure before the page break to the landscape page, if that is what you meant. So, I guess I am stuck with manually labelling the figures if I want the landscape page to "float", right?

Comment: "robustness" in this case means "afterpage redefines parts of the latex output routine that were never intended to be redefined and it's somewhat surprising that it works at all,  even more so that lots of people seem to use it a quarter of a century later" :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think I got it: I should be more than happy with manually relabelling the figures given that I want the text to float around the landscape page. :-)

Comment: or use `\begin{figure}[p]` for figure 1 (you still haven't shown a usable example so it's hard to say what should and should not work)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Finally, I managed to produce the example. I have tried to add the [p] option to the landscape figure but it doesn't make a difference. The other figures should not be on their own page but in the text.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what do you want to achieve? Do you want the figures not to change their position in text? Or do you want to change the numbering so that fig 1 will be on the first page, fig 3 on the second (landscape page) and then fig 2 on the third page?

In case 1 you can use the `float` package which adds an option [H] (uppercase H instead of default latex lowercase h). It forces the float to stay exactly where it is put in the text. The code will look like this:

```
\begin{figure}[H] 
%figure
\end{figure}
```

Regarding case 2, you can change the numbering of the figures by changing the `figure` counter like this:

```
%figure1
\addtocounter{figure}{1}
%figure3
\addtocounter{figure}{-2}
%figure2
\addtocounter{figure}{1}
```

Then you'll have first figure 1 then figure 3 then figure 2 then figure 4, 5, 6...

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to correct my vague comment. I actually tried to achieve case 2. However, it would be great of course if I would not have to handle the numbering manually.

Comment: Note that while the form shown in the question should not ever make floats go out of sequence using `[H]` makes the figure a non-float and so it can then get out of sequence with floats which may float past it unless you use `\clearpage` to stop them (or correct the numbering by hand)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Figures go out of sequence independently of the [H] option. But I would like them to appear in sequence hence correcting numbering by hand does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

LaTeX will keep floats in order but...

If you use afterpage the latex commands are only interpreted hen the delayed text is inserted so that figure is figure 2, so in that case the numbering and ordering (as seen in the table of contents) is correct it is just the caption text is wrong. But presumably no real caption would be "figure two" in words.

The situation with `[H]` is different. If you use `[H]` then you are asserting manual control and that figure will not move, even if other figures float past it, in that case it is your responsibility to force the correct float numbering.

I don't think you need `\afterpage` or `[H]` here (I'm somewhat responsible for both those things and I wouldn't use them here)  Just allow Latex to number floats as usual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\blindtext[4]
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
... figure contents ...
\caption{Figure 1}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\begin{figure}
... figure contents ...
\caption{Figure 2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
... figure contents ...
\caption{Figure 3}
\end{figure}
\blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, first, the captions going the wrong way around is just a symptom of the problem. The problem is that the order in which figures appear is changed. For example, if I reference the figures in text I would like them to appear in order I reference them first without having to fiddle around with their placement manually. Second, as for your proposed solution of using `sidewaysfigure` it does not put the pages in landscape which makes it non-ideal for online reading.

Comment: @Daniel the order hasn't changed by accident or due to some subtle interaction, it has been explicitly delayed and is not inserted until later as you wrapped it in `\afterpage` I am not sure what else you would expect it to do? the content of `\afterpage` isn't evaluated at all, it's just as if you used it in `\newcommand\tmp{\begin{figure}......}` and then `\tmp` gets used later in the document (in fact that is essentially exactly what does happen)

Comment: I was hoping that `\afterpage` could help me to get the following: 1. figures on pages in landscape, and 2. figures in the order they are inserted. So, if I understand you correctly, `\afterpage` cannot be used for this since it fails to deliver 2. So, I am still searching for a solution to getting both 1 and 2 done. 1 and 2 together seems like the obvious things one would want when creating landscape figures for online reading.

Comment: @Daniel it delivers 2 if you understand "inserted" the way tex  understands  it, `\afterpage` stores the argument in a macro and inserts it later it's just as if you have defined `\tmpfiga`  and `\tmpfigb` in the preamble, The place and order that the macro is defined is not recorded by TeX, what matters is where it is used (which in this case is at the top of the next page, after the other figure has already been set as figure 1)

Comment: I am not sure I can follow you. My point was: TeX normally shows figures in the order I write them in the document using the `figure` environment. That makes sense since then one can make sure one references them in the right order. This works also with `sidewaysfigure`. But I am looking for a way to get the order as expected and the figures on a landscape page. None of the answers suggested achieve this.

Comment: @Daniel if you go `\def\figa{\begin{figure}\caption{first figure}\end{figure}}\def\figb{\begin{figure}\caption{second figure}\end{figure}}...\figb...\figa`  then tex will not see the figures in the order that you wrote them, it will see them in the order the macros are executed so "second figure" will be figure 1. that is what happens if you use `\afterpage`. The figure is not seen by tex until the next page when the internal command saving the text is executed. So that is forcing it to be executed after the first figure has already been typeset. That is what afterpage does by design.

Comment: So, `\afterpage` seems not the right way to go then. Maybe there just is currently no easy way in (La)TeX to achieve what I desire. It's surprising.

Comment: @Daniel the reason why sideways figure doesn't rotate the page view is that it doesn't control the page, if you have a table in the top of a page that has been rotated, followed by half a page of normal portrait orientation text, it isn't clear that rotating the page view is the right thing to do. (pdf)lscape is generating complete rotated pages so there the situation is different.

Comment: No, that seems wrong. `sidewaysfigure`, in addition to rotating, always creates an extra page, so that no other non-rotated stuff is on that page. So, rotating the page would be the right thing to do.

Comment: @Daniel sorry you are right, I was thinking of rotcaption, adding `\pdfpageattr{/Rotate 90}`  to the figure probably works then....

Comment: `sidewaysfigure` does exactly what I want minus the page rotation. Close but no cigar.