# How to make one page adapt a portrait orientation when the rest is in landscape

Tags: landscape, page, pagestyle

I am working on a document which is primarily in landscape. However one page contains a portrait image and I would like to display it in upright position. Basically I am asking if there is a reverse version of the typical portrait to landscape page orientation questions that is usually asked.

[EDIT: To clarify, I want to display the Page 2 in portrait when using a PDF viewer]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in, landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\Blindtext

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{PrettyLisa.jpg}
\caption{Mona Lisa}
\label{Mona}
\end{sidewaysfigure} %%%%How can I display this in portrait orientation?%%%%

\end{document}
```

Comment: it is not clear what you want, sidewaysfigure or the landscape evironment from pdflscape would give a figure in the opposite orientation, but if you just mean you do not want to rotate the figure, just use a normal figure environment and replace `[width=\linewidth]` by say `[height=.7\textheight]`

Comment: Does "display" mean that you want to rotate the view in the pdf viewer?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. To clarify yes I want to display the second page in portrait when using a pdf viewer.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472608/2388